# Simple nodejs websocket code is consuming high Memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection, heap-memory

Using simple websocket code in nodejs but it taking high Memory.

1. Concurrent clients are 200
2. Exchange chat messages, each message send to all connected client (broadcast message)
3. Message frequency 50-60 messages per seconds and message length maximum 10 KB
4. Process handle by PM2
5. Heap memory size 400 MiB
6. used heap Memory 40%
7. RAM consumption reached upto 4 GB in 15-20 Mins, then process restarts.

Here is my code.
I am not storing any data in variables but still memory is consuming..

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
 
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domainnanem/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domainnanem/cert.pem', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domainnanem/chain.pem', 'utf8');

const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: ca
};

 

 app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'html', 'index.html'));
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'app.js'));
  });
  
 
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

 

httpsServer.listen(9992, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 9992');
});

var url = require('url');


var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    server: httpsServer
});
wss.on('connection', function (ws,req) {
      const { query: { token } } = url.parse(req.url, true);
      ws.room=token;
     
      
  ws.on('message', function (message) {
   
   wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
     
       if(client.room==ws.room){
          
         
             if (client.readyState == ws.OPEN) { 
                client.send(message); 
             }        
          
       }
   });
     
});
 
});
```

Comment: Have you made a heap snapshot to see which objects are allocated?

Comment: pm2 monit  command on server

Comment: how can i take snapshot on server?